# Not able to check if time exist in tow Time fields (MySQL , C#, windowsform application)

Tags: c#, mysql, time

I have two Time fields in mysql database. I need to check before adding a new time, i try this code.

```
private bool TimeFound()
{
    MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(DB.GetCS("127.0.0.1", "3306",
        "db", "root", "password", "utf8"));
    string query = "SELECT time.From, time.To FROM db.time WHERE " +
        "(time.From, time.To) NOT IN (SELECT time.From, time.To FROM db.time " +
        "WHERE (time.From = @From AND time.To = @To";
    cnn.Open();
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, cnn);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@From", dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@To", dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
    object result = command.ExecuteScalar();
    if (result == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Every time I try to call the function I get error at this line.

```
object result = command.ExecuteScalar();
```

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1'

Comment: (1) Why the need for such a convoluted query? _when the subquery is all you need_ (2) it's missing a couple `)`.

Comment: how i miss this, its working now, thanks man, can you give me an example to make simpler query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we've already covered, you were missing two closing parenthesis, but your query seems overcomplicated.

```
SELECT time.From, time.To 
FROM db.time 
WHERE (time.From, time.To) NOT IN (
   SELECT time.From, time.To 
   FROM db.time 
   WHERE (time.From = @From AND time.To = @To)
)
```

should not have results that differ in any way from just

```
SELECT time.From, time.To 
FROM db.time 
WHERE (time.From = @From AND time.To = @To)
```

---

Every query of the form

```
SELECT x, y FROM a WHERE (x, y) IN (SELECT x, y FROM a WHERE x = x1 AND y = y1)
```

is the same as

```
SELECT x, y FROM a WHERE x = x1 AND y = y1
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the comment from Uueerdo, missing 2 )) at the end of the query, i don't know how i miss this.